# How to select_related when using .get() in django?

Tags: django

If I use the `get()` function to get one item from the model, I cannot use `select_related()`, as that object doesn't have it, but I'd still like to use it to save myself one DB query.
What I'm saying is that this doesn't work (and I'd like it to):

```
MyModel.objects.get(id=100).select_related('related_model')
```

What I *can* do is not what was intended. I can do this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(id=100).select_related('related_model')[0]
```

But it's not the same. Can I do something about it?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I *think*

```
MyModel.objects.select_related('related_model').get(id=100)
```

works, but I can't test it right now.

Comment: Silly me :). Should have known.

Comment: For large numbers of `MyModel` wouldn't this be much slower than `MyModel.objects.filter(id=100).select_related('related_model').get()` since it has to do the related join on _all_ `MyModel` objects instead of just the filtered list?

Comment: @AddisonKlinke: I expect them both to turn into the exact same SQL query when evaluated. Eventually the query contains "WHERE id = 100" so the database should know it doesn't have to join all rows.